# Calling bash script from ant in (linux) and (cygwin on windows)

Tags: windows, bash, unix, ant, cygwin

I have a `bash` script called `bashScript.sh`.

I need to start `bashScript.sh` inside an `ant` script on windows(cygwin) and unix/linux.

How do i do this?

I have tried this, and a few other solutions, using the environment variable but there is no `env.OSTYPE`. And using...

```
    <exec executable="/bin/bash" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="bashScript.sh"/>
    </exec>
```

...does not work on windows(cygwin), because cygwin fails to find `\bin\bash`.

Thanks, if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create two `exec` tasks with different `osfamily`s.

Like this:

```
<exec dir="." executable="C:\Path\to\cygwin\bin\bash" osfamily="windows">
    <arg value="bashScript.sh"/>
</exec>
<exec dir="." executable="/bin/bash" osfamily="unix">
     <arg value="bashScript.sh"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Attempting this solution now.

Comment: That worked, minus all the extra `arg values` you have in the `exec`. However, i was hoping for a solution where the path to `\bin\bash` was not hard coded. Is there a way to derive that path, so the user does not have to change it based on their cygwin location?

Comment: I modified your answer. I took out some of the extra stuff that was not needed.